# why use zend form decorators instead of individually rendering?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I am almost at the end of my rope trying to style my Zend form using decorators.  Previously to avoid these issues I would create a form script extending zend_form, add whatever validators, labels, etc I needed then retrieved the element from my view script using  `$form->getElement('my_form_element');`

that way I could wrap whatever css tags I wanted around the element.  I thought I should learn how to use the built in decorators, but I'm starting to feel like it's a waste of my time.  My old way seems easier, is there some reason I am not seeing that makes using custom decorators better?

Comment: Don't spend to much time on decorators, there is a whole new system for Zend_Form in ZF2, they've gone away from decorators and have gone to viewHelpers. Hopefully it will be easier.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you are using `<?= $form->getElement('my_form_element') ?>`, then you are implicitly using the decorators attached to the elements themselves (like the ViewHelper, Label, Description, Errors, etc). Of course, if you dig deeper to get the more granular components of the element itself - like `$elt->getLabel()` - then you truly are avoiding the decorators. Still, I find that unless I create custom view helpers to render the form elements, my custom form-rendering view-scripts have a lot of repeated boilerplate markup in them that would otherwise be DRY using decorators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general decorators are used to dynamically add functionality without having to touch the code's core functionality and for a better re-usage of code. In `Zend_Form` however, I think that the decorator system  (as well as `Zend_Form` in general) is unintuitive and heavily over-engineered and so it does exactly the opposite of what it should do: Help the developer to create better and more intuitive code faster.

In my opinion the usage of `Zend_Form_Decorator` makes only sense in the case where you have some extended logic that you plan to reuse throughout your project on multiple and different types of elements.

Let me give you two examples:

1. You want to add a tooltip icon next to an arbitrary form element with a nice icon and a fancy JavaScript hover box.
2. An element should be validated directly upon entering data by posting an AJAX request and adding either a green check mark on success or a red cross icon on failure next to the element.

With the decorator you can now separate the logic of the added functionality from that of the underlying element and so you can use the same code to add the tooltip and/or the live validation feature to a textbox element as well as any other element simply by adding all the decorators you want to the element.

There is also a great article from Matthew Weier O'Phinney, the lead developer of Zend Framwork, that gives some background insight on the motivations for using decorators along with a lot of examples: [Decorators with Zend_Form](http://devzone.zend.com/1240/decorators-with-zend_form/)

Comment: Very experienced developers in my team still don't fully understand these decorators. It's more of a trial and error process, hoping it looks like you want it to look at some point! ( We still have lots of legacy code in ZF1.12 ).

Answer (score 1):

Decorators can come in handy if you have a specific repeatable markup for your forms, for example if you want to use Bootstrap. Other than that, especially if you have a good html/css person, I would avoid them.